# reading input from keyboard

Tags: c++, string, stdin

I am required to read from an keyboard(stdin), the following text. Pl note that it will be entered by user from keyboard in this format only.

```
 #the total size of physical memory (units are B, KB, MB, GB)
    512MB   2       #the following are memory allocations
    {
            abc = alloc(1KB);
             {
                y_ = alloc(128MB);
                x1= alloc(128MB);
                y_ = alloc(32MB);
               for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) abc[i] =alloc(512kB);
                  x1 = alloc(32MB); x2 = alloc(32MB); x3 = alloc(32MB);
               x1.next = x2, x2.next = x3, x3.next = x1;
    }
    abc = alloc(256MB);
    }
```

So basically let me break it down.
a line beginning with # sign is considered as comment and is ignored. 
the first two allocations are physical memory size and number of generations.
a global bracket will be opened.
and it may be followed by a line called

```
abc = alloc(1KB);
```

where abc is the object name, 1KB is the memory size allocated.
`x1.next = x2,` here x1 points to x2.

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) abc[i] =alloc(512kB);
```

the for loop os entered in this format and it can have a same line command or can have nested for loops.

I have the following code that takes care of this somewhat. I want to know improve on it. Please do help.

And my code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>



using namespace std;
using std::stringstream;

string pMem,sGen, comment,val,input,input_for,id_size,id,init_str1, init_str2, inc_str, id_dummy,s_out,sss, id_dummy1;
int gen=0, pMem_int=0,i=0, gBrckt =0,cBrckt=0, oBrckt=0, id_size_int,v1,v2, for_oBrckt=0,for_cBrckt=0,y=0, y1=0, g=0;
unsigned long pMem_ulong =0, id_size_ulong;
char t[20], m[256], init1[10],init2[10],inc[10];
unsigned pos_start, pos,pos_strt=0,pos_end=0;

string extract(string pMem_extract);
unsigned long toByte(int pMem_int_func, string val);
void commentIgnore(string& input);
void func_insert();
void func_insert_for();
stringstream out;
void commentIgnore_for(string& input_for);

int main() 
{
  /* Reading the input main memory and num of generations */
  /* Ignoring comment line */
  cin >> pMem;
  if(pMem == "#") {
    cin.clear();
    pMem.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> pMem;
  }
  if(pMem == "#") {
    cin.clear();
    pMem.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> pMem;
  }
  if(pMem == "#") {
    cin.clear();
    pMem.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> pMem;
    }
  /* Reading input generations */
  cin>> sGen;
  if(sGen == "#") {
    cin.clear();
    sGen.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> sGen;
  }
  if(sGen == "#") {
    cin.clear();
    sGen.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> sGen;
  }
  if(sGen == "#") {
    cin.clear();
    sGen.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> sGen;
  }
  /* Convert sGen and physical memory to int and report error if not a number */
  gen = atoi(sGen.c_str());
  if(gen ==0) {
    cerr << "Generation must be a number"<<endl;
      exit(0);
  }
  pMem_int = atoi(pMem.c_str());
  //  cout<< gen<<" "<<pMem_int<<endl;

  /* Now that the number from pMem is removed, get its unit B,MB,KB */
  extract(pMem); /* returns val(string) */

  /* convert the given physical memory to Byte. input: pMem_int*/
  toByte(pMem_int, val); /*  return(pMem_ulong)*/
  // move pMem_ulond to another location to keep address intact
  /* read rest of the inputs  */
  /* Ignore comment lines before the global bracket */
   cin >> input;
  if(input == "#"){
    cin.clear();
    input.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> input;
  }
  if(input == "#"){
    cin.clear();
    input.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> input;
  }
  if(input == "#"){
    cin.clear();
    input.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> input;
  }

  if(input.compare("{") ==0)
    gBrckt=1;

  else {
    cerr<< "Syntax error\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  /* Clearing the input stream for next input */
  cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  cin.clear();
  input.clear();
  //cout<<"input: "<<input<<endl;
  while( getline(cin,input)) {

    if(input == "CTRL-D")
      break;

    commentIgnore(input);
    //cout<<"inputloop: "<<input<<endl;

    /* If input = '{' or '}'*/
    if(input.compare("{") ==0)
      oBrckt = oBrckt + 1;

     if (input.compare("}") ==0)
      cBrckt = cBrckt + 1;

     if (((input.find("alloc"))!= string::npos) && (input.find("alloc") < input.find("for"))) {
       func_insert();
       //call the allocate function here with name: id, size: id_size_ulong
     }

     if ((input.find("for")) != string::npos) {
        sscanf(input.c_str(), "for (%s = %d; %s < %d; %[^)])", init1, &v1, init2, &v2, inc);
    init_str1 = init1, init_str2 = init2, inc_str = inc;

    cout<<init1<<" ="<< v1<<" "<<init_str1<<" < " << v2<< " "<< inc_str<<endl;
    cout << input <<endl;

    if(init_str1 != init_str2) {
      cerr << "Error!\n";
      exit(0);
    }

    if ((input.find("alloc"))!= string::npos) {
      // unsigned pos = (input.find("alloc"));

      if((input.find(";")) != string::npos) {

         pos_start = (input.find(")")+1);
        string alloc_substr  = input.substr(pos_start);
        cout<<"Substring alloc: "<< alloc_substr<<endl;

        func_insert();
        //call the allocate function here with name: id, size: id_size_ulong
      }
      else {
        cerr << "ERROR: SYNTAX\n";
        exit(0);
      }


    }
    //  cin.ignore();
    while(getline(cin,input_for)) {
      commentIgnore_for(input_for);

      if ((input_for.find("{") != string::npos)) {
        pos = input_for.find("{");
        for_oBrckt = for_oBrckt+1;
        string for_brckt = input_for.substr(pos,pos);
        cout<< "Found: " << for_oBrckt<<endl;
      }


      if ((input_for.find("}") != string::npos)) {
         pos = input_for.find("}");
        for_cBrckt = for_cBrckt+1;
        string for_brckt = input_for.substr(pos,pos);
        cout<< "Found: " << for_cBrckt<<endl;
      }

      if (((input_for.find("alloc"))!= string::npos) && (input_for.find("alloc") < input_for.find("for"))) {
        func_insert_for();
        //call the allocate function here with name: id, size: id_size_ulong
      }




      if(for_oBrckt == for_cBrckt)
        break;


    }
    cout<<"out of break"<<endl;
     }

      if (((input.find(".next"))!= string::npos) && (input.find(".next") < input.find("for"))) {
       func_insert();
       //call the allocate function here with name: id, size: id_size_ulong
     }

      if(((cBrckt-oBrckt)) == gBrckt)
       break;
  }

}

/*---------------------- Function definitions --------------------------------*/
/* Function to extract the string part of physical memory */
string extract(string pMem_extract) {
  i=0;
  const char *p = pMem_extract.c_str();
  for(i=0; i<=(pMem_extract.length()); i++) {
    if (*p=='0'|| *p=='1'|| *p=='2'|| *p=='3'|| *p =='4'|| *p=='5'|| *p=='6'|| *p=='7'|| *p=='8'|| *p=='9')
      *p++;
    else {
      val = pMem_extract.substr(i);
      return(val);
    }
  }
}

/* Convert the physical memory to bytes. return(pMem_ulong);*/
unsigned long toByte(int pMem_int_func, string val)
{
  if (val == "KB")
    pMem_ulong =  (unsigned long) pMem_int_func * 1024;
  else if (val == "B")
    pMem_ulong = (unsigned long) pMem_int_func;
  else if (val == "GB")
    pMem_ulong = (unsigned long) pMem_int_func * 1073741824;
  else if (val == "MB")
    pMem_ulong = (unsigned long) pMem_int_func * 1048576;
  else {
    cerr<<"Missing the value in memory, B, KB, MB, GB\n";
    exit(0);
  }

  return(pMem_ulong);
}


/*Ignoring comment line*/
void commentIgnore(string& input)
{
  unsigned found = input.find('#');

  if (found!=std::string::npos)
   input= input.erase(found);

  else
    return;
  return;
}


void func_insert() {
 sscanf(input.c_str(), "%s = alloc(%[^)]);", t, m);
       id =t;
       id_size =m;
       cout<<"Tag: "<<id <<"  Memory: "<<id_size<<endl;
       extract(id_size); /* Separates B,MB,KB and GB of input, returns val*/
       id_size_int = atoi(id_size.c_str());
       /* Convert object size to B */
       toByte(id_size_int, val); /* return(pMem_ulong) */
       id_size_ulong = pMem_ulong;

}

void func_insert_for() {
  sscanf(input_for.c_str(), "%s = alloc(%[^)]);", t, m);
  id =t;
  id_size =m;
  if(!((id.find("[")) && (id.find("]")) != string::npos)) {
    cout<<"Tag: "<<id <<"  Memory: "<<id_size<<endl;
    extract(id_size); /* Separates B,MB,KB and GB of input, returns val*/
    id_size_int = atoi(id_size.c_str());
    /* Convert object size to B */
    toByte(id_size_int, val); /* return(pMem_ulong) */
    id_size_ulong = pMem_ulong;
    // allocate here
    return;
  }
  else {
    if(inc_str.find("++"))
      y1 =1;
    if(inc_str.find("="))
      {
    sss = inc_str.substr(inc_str.find("+") +1);
    y1 = atoi(sss.c_str());
    cout<<"y1:"<<y1<<endl;

      }
    pos_strt = id.find("[");
    pos_end = id.find("]") -1;
    cout<<"Positions start and ebd: " << pos_strt<<pos_end<<endl;
    id_dummy = id.substr(0,pos_strt);
    id = id_dummy;
    cout<<"Tag: "<<id_dummy <<"  Memory: "<<id_size<<endl;
    extract(id_size); /* Separates B,MB,KB and GB of input, returns val*/
    id_size_int = atoi(id_size.c_str());
    /* Convert object size to B */
    toByte(id_size_int, val); /* return(pMem_ulong) */
    id_size_ulong = pMem_ulong;
    //allocate here
    cout<<"v1: " << v1 << " " << v2<<endl;
    // g = 0;
    for(y = v1; y < v2; y= y+y1) {
      // allocate here
    }
  }
  return;
}

void commentIgnore_for(string& input_for)
{
  unsigned found = input_for.find('#');

  if (found!=std::string::npos)
   input_for= input_for.erase(found);

  else
    return;
  return;
}
```

Also i am required to make it whitespace compatible. What it means is that input can be entered in one line as well. like two allocations in one line. Which  i have not been able to taken care. I need help with that.

Comment: I think this may be better suited for [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious : I have a problem seeing a question in there...

Comment: i am required to make it whitespace compatible. What it means is that input can be entered in one line as well. like two allocations in one line. Which i dont think i have taken care of. I need help with that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Indeed.

Comment: Your approach is pretty poor. It would be much better to write a function that gives you a token. I'll write up an answer for that.

Comment: Yes.. It is actually quite poor. I am trying to compact it as much as possible..

Comment: If you are looking to parse the input text string, perhaps a more organized approach, e.g. based on [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) would be better.

Comment: Pretty sure most of that code has nothing to do with the question. Please delete it and come up with an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Actually that code reads inputs from the keyboard and stores values for further computations.

Comment: The functions that were defined were a few added things though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be that you write a proper tokenizer - a piece of code that understands what belongs together (such as "words"), and where to split (e.g. "(, ), {, }"). The tokenizer would return an enum, something like this:

```
enum Token {
    Token_Unknown,   // Error indiciation. 
    Token_LeftParen,
    Token_RightParen,
    Token_LeftBracket,
    Token_RightBracket,
    Token_Comma,
    Token_Semicolon, 
    Token_Equal,
    Token_Word,        // Sequence of alphanumerics
};
```

Once you have a token, you need to understand what that token is. It may make sense to have a table of "known" tokens (aka "keywords"), such as "mem", "alloc", "for", and so on. If something isn't a keyword, it's the name of a symbol, such as a variable. You store those in a table, so that you can refer to them later.

You will have to use some sort of stack of where you are, so you can get back to where you came from when you finish.

Writing a generic parser isn't terribly hard, and you will most likely end up with a lot less code than your current code in doing so.

Certainly, you'd be able to get rid of all the:

```
  if(input == "#"){
    cin.clear();
    input.clear();
    getline(cin,comment);
    cin >> input;
  }
```

Just let the parser check if there is a `'#'` as the input, and skip over to the end of the line (completing the current token if you have one, if not, just keep going).

Comment: There are freely available tools which will generate both the tokenizer and the parser; these should be used, rather than writing everything by hand.

Comment: And why the `clear()` after you've seen the start of a comment?  Just skip ahead until you see the next end of line.  (This could be a rule in the tokenizer, or you can insert a filtering streambuf in the input stream.)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the input is *not* line oriented, so the usual rule of
using `std::getline` may not apply.  My own approach would be:

- Insert a filtering streambuf to removed the comments.
- Use some sort of regular expression based lexer (e.g. `flex`)
  to break the input up into tokens.
- Define the grammar; I'd use `bison` once I'd gotten this far,
  in order to generate the code to parse the grammar, but a simple
  recursive descent parser shouldn't be too hard to write.

You don't say what you must do with the information once you
have parsed it, so it's hard to give more precise advice.

Comment: basically, i allocate the given physicalmemory and divide it by number of generations. when i come across alloc, i allocate the object with the memory specified by alloc in the physical memory.

Comment: In the for loop, i allocate recursively. This is a garbage collection algorithm that i am working on. x1.net = x2 makes the x1 point to x2. it is a linked list.